# angularJS partials added path to url instead of rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am building a single page app that I would like to split into partials. Most information is coming from an external api, but also storing that information in own api/db.

Right now the code looks like:

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
  <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
      <nav ng-include="'partials/navigation'">
      </nav>
<body>
```

In my console I receive the error "GET http://localhost:3000/partials/navigation 404 (Not Found)". I'm not quite sure why this is happening.

I thought about having two controllers – one controller with the external API requests, one for partial control – but that doensn't seem to work either.

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as ctrl">
  <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </header>
    <div ng-controller="PartialsController as ctrl">
      <nav ng-include="'partials/navigation'">
      </nav>
    </div>
<body>
```

Comment: you should better stop using ng-include and ng-controller, and write directives or components. It will clarify you code.

Comment: I am very beginner with angularJS and am not quite sure what you mean. Can I not get it to work with ng-include and ng-controller?